# Does this sum/product have a closed form?: $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \prod\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^x}$

Tags: summation, closed-form, infinite-product

I was just messing around in desmos when I came across this interesting function:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^x}$$

You can see it has a couple of interesting features, including asymptotes at x=0 and y=2, and its value at 1 is e.

[image]
I’m wondering if this has a closed form. It appears like a smooth function but I’ve never worked with infinite products.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a closed form. First use product notation properties:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\prod_{k=1}^n k\right)^{-x}$$

then the definition of the factorial and the [Pochhammer symbol $(a)_b$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Pochhammer+Symbol):
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\prod_{k=1}^n k\right)^{-x} =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n!^x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(1)_n^{x-1}n!}$$

Now use the [Hypergeometric function $\,_p\text F_q$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=HypergeometricPFQ):

$$f(x)=\,_0\text F_{x-1}(\underbrace{1,…,1}_{x-1\text{ times}};1),x\in\Bbb N $$

[**See values of the function here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=hypergeometricpfq%28%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C1%29+%2Chypergeometricpfq%28%7B%7D%2C%7B1%7D%2C1%29%2C+hypergeometricpfq%28%7B%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%7D%2C1%29%2C+hypergeometricpfq%28%7B%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%7D%2C1%29)

There are unfortunately only $4$ “special cases” with one using the [Bessel I](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=BesselI) function from this result:

$$f(0)\to\infty$$
$$f(1)=e$$
$$f(2)=\text I_0(2)$$
$$f(\infty)\to2$$

How about for $x\not\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: Very interesting indeed! I wasn’t expecting Bessel functions to pop up